# Check Javascript array to see if value begins with certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to go through an array and check to see if any of the array elements begin with a certain value.

```
var availableForms = new Array("S1", "S2", "S2_2", "S3", "S3_2", "S3_3", "S3_4", "S3_5", "S4");    

var classNumber = 1;  

var isComplete = $.map(availableForms, function (value, index) {
    if($.inArray("S"+classNumber, value) != 0) 
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Above `isComplete` should be `true`.

Also, if `classNumber = 2` it should also return true. I basically am just checking for anything before the `_` when those exist, but if there is no `_` then it can match it.

Right now it is only returning:

```
[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

Comment: 2nd argument for `$.inArray` is supposed to be array. And in your case what type does `value` have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map()` methods are for constructing a new Array of values that map to the original values, and I'm not sure why you're using `$.inArray` on a string.

Sounds like you want the native `.some()` method.

```
var availableForms = new Array("S1", "S2", "S2_2", "S3", "S3_2", "S3_3", "S3_4", "S3_5", "S4");    

var classNumber = 1;  

var isComplete = availableForms.some(function(s) {
    return s === "S" + classNumber;
});
```

As long as at least one value in the iteration returns a true result from the callback, `.some()` will return `true`, otherwise `false`.

You can patch `.some()` into older browsers easily.

---

Or if you must use jQuery, use `$.grep`, and compare the length of the result.

```
var availableForms = new Array("S1", "S2", "S2_2", "S3", "S3_2", "S3_3", "S3_4", "S3_5", "S4");    

var classNumber = 1;  

var isComplete = $.grep(availableForms, function(s) {
    return s === "S" + classNumber;
}).length > 0;
```

This is generally like the native `Array.prototype.filter` method.

Comment: Ah `some` works perfectly (as of your edit :p ), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants a non-jQuery method you could simply iterate over the array:

```
var availableForms = new Array("S1", "S2", "S2_2", "S3", "S3_2", "S3_3", "S3_4", "S3_5", "S4");    

var classNumber = 1;  
var isComplete = false;

for (var i = 0;i<availableForms.length;i++){
    if (availableForms[i] === "S" + classNumber){
        isComplete = true;
    }
}
```

Or, as an alternate (and maybe better) method, you could make an array of the first 2 character of each item in availableForms:

```
var availableForms = new Array("S1", "S2", "S2_2", "S3", "S3_2", "S3_3", "S3_4", "S3_5", "S4");

var classNumber = 1;  
var isComplete = false;
var firstCharacters = new Array();

for (var i = 0;i<availableForms.length;i++){
    firstCharacters.push(availableForms[i].slice(0,2));
}

if (firstCharacters.indexOf('S'+classNumber) > -1){
    isComplete = true;
}
```

I'm sure there are many betters ways, but this seems good off the top off my head.

Update:

I just noticed that cookiemonster already has a non-jQuery answer, so let me revise to: if anyone wants a for-loop answer, this would do it.